# parse json string to array

Tags: php, codeigniter, json

I can't parse this json string given below, anybody suggest some good option:

```
$json_string = '{{"name":"ff","phone":344543},{"name":"sdf","phone":344543},       {"name":"sfsd","phone":344543}}';

i have tried json_decode($json_string); but not working. I need to parse this string and retrieve the coontants as normal array. please help.
```

Thanks

Comment: Your string isn't valid JSON.

Comment: BTW use `json_decode($json_string, TRUE);` instead.

Comment: it is working, may i know what does that second parameter true means?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @VeNaToR It returns an `array` instead of `stdClass` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first object is without a key. Two consecutive {{ are not allowed in JSON. Replace the first { with a [. And of course the last closing } with a ] to make it a valid array.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON string is incorrect,
correct way:

```
$json_string = '[{"name":"ff","phone":344543},{"name":"sdf","phone":344543},{"name":"sfsd","phone":344543}]';
print_r(json_decode($json_string));
```

try above thing..